# Create new workbook from office script

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I would like to create a new excel workbook from office script. Is it possible to create a new workbook and give it a dynamic name (date) in office script itself?

Comment: You could use Microsoft Graph. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I don't believe this operation is currently supported with Office Scripts.

Answer (score 5):

This is supported by using Office Scripts in combination with Power Automate. You can pass the dynamic name as a return value for the office script, and this can be used by the "Create file" Power Automate connector. Your Power Automate flow would look something like this -

[image: Power Automate flow]

The `result` value is what is returned by the Office Script. This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration#return-data-from-a-script) provides details on how you can return data from Office Scripts.

The `File Content` is returned by the `Get File Content` action. This can be a template/blank excel file.

The flow example I have above runs another script on the newly created file. This way you can do more actions on the new file if required.